# how to deserialize JSON array to list ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to consume JSON using jackson.

The class that i want to bind my json is:-

**KeyValueModel.class**

```
public class KeyValueModel {

    private String k1;
    private String k2;
    public String getK1() {
        return k1;
    }
    public void setK1(String k1) {
        this.k1 = k1;
    }
    public String getK2() {
        return k2;
    }
    public void setK2(String k2) {
        this.k2 = k2;
    }
}
```

I want to map the json directly to my list of my model i.e KeyValueModel

```
    @Test
    public void whenParsingJsonStringIntoList_thenCorrect() throws IOException {


    String jsonList = "{
  "count": 30,
  "data": [
    {
      "k1": "v1",
      "k2": "v2"
    },
    {
      "k1": "no",
      "k2": "yes"
    }
  ]
}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, KeyValueModel.class);

        List<KeyValueModel> l = mapper.readValue(jsonList, listType);

        System.out.println(l.get(1).getK2());

        assertNotNull(l);


}
```

i get an error which says

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "count": 30,
  "data": [
    {
      "k1": "v1",
      "k2": "v2"
    },
    {
      "k1": "no",
      "k2": "yes"
    }
  ]
}";
```

how to i deserialize the  data array to the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your json data, it is an object but you are trying to parse it as a list, the list you are looking for in the json string is stored in the field **data**, so try something like this.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(your_json_string);
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

Now you can easily get your desired list of objects by passing **array.toString()** to the object mapper

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GSON library, this should work:

```
  Type type = new TypeToken<List<KeyValueModel>>(){}.getType();
  List<KeyValueModel> l = new Gson().fromJson(jsonList,type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one more class because you have one more property count in your json string

```
public class Test{

    private String count;
    private KeyValueModel[] kv;

}
```

then change your code to

```
Test test = mapper.readValue(jsonList, Test.class);
System.out.println(test.getKv()[0].getK1()) will get the expected result
```